# I want to run python file(program which generates 10 blank text files) when clicked on button in Php

Tags: php, python, html

I have a python file which generates 10 blank files. I have another php file with html button. When the button is pressed the python script should run.
When I run python file on terminal, it works fine and generates blank files.
But when i click button on php, it does nothing. 
Can anyone help me out with this problem?

The php and python files are attached below.

upload.py:

```html
for i in range(0,10):
 f=open(str(i)+"upload.txt", "a")
 f.write("This is line")
f.close()
```

upload.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>  
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">

    <input type="submit" value="GO" name="GO">
   </form>
    
 
  </body>
</html>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['GO']))
  {
    shell_exec("python upload.py");
    echo"success";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Why? There are trillions of tutorials to do it either in `PHP` or `Python` - why should you mix it with some shell_exec workaround?

Comment: I'm doing a project in python and my UI is designed on html and Php. I want to integrate this python file which generate files when clicked by a button on php page